# Refresh/reset dynamically updated page in jquery mobile 1.4+

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have cordova/phonegap app on iOS8 jqm 1.4+

When a user logs in I download a database and change a bunch of visual elements based on the data. Now, if this user logs out and another user logs in on the same device during the same session I need the view to "reset" as if this were a brand-new session. Realistically this only applies to 2 pages in the DOM.

`.trigger("create")` would be the normal method to refresh/reset a page but this is deprecated and was replaced with `.enhanceWithin()` which I can't get to work.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Are you calling `.enhanceWithin()` on parent div that accommodates dynamic elements? You can call it on page too `$("#pageID").enhanceWhithin();`.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: can create a fiddle with a sample code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8uac7/1607/ @Omar

Comment: `.enhanceWithin()` isn't meant to _reset_, it's used to _enhance_ dynamically created items. If you want to remove elements, use `.empty()` or `.remove()` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/8uac7/1608/

Comment: So is there no way of kind of blanket resetting the html markup in the DOM with jqm? I'm presenting many figures in various <div> and <p> tags, with a new user do I have to effectively change them all back manually? Can I not recreate the same as a new app session somehow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64737/discussion-between-omar-and-oliverj90).

Comment: updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ot6a3n79/1/

Comment: I got a similar issue: when the user taps on the "refresh" button, I need to refresh the content of a div, which dynamically loads content obtained via ajax and creates a series of divs with content using an `each()` function.

The problem is, when I use `remove()` or `empty()` it tends to unbind the events idk why.

I also tried to remove and create the pages using `.trigger('remove')` and `.trigger('create') but it doesn't removes the content itself, so it shows duplicate data, and if I add `remove()` or `empty()` to the process it unbinds events.

what can I do?